# Java RMI NotBoundException while executing with ant

Tags: java, ant, rmi

I'm trying to write a little game with Java RMI and I have to use Apache Ant to run it.
Unfortunately, when I use ant to execute the server and the client jar, it crashes with a NotBoundException. But when I execute the jars via command line (java -jar ...), everything works fine. I can't figure out what's going wrong with the ant script.

Important Server Code:

```
public class GameServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IGameServer {

    public GameServer() throws RemoteException {
        //...
    }

    // some methods here

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
        RemoteServer.setLog(System.out);

        // create new GameServer Object and make it available via the Registry
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        GameServer server = new GameServer();
        registry.rebind("GameServer", server);
    }

}
```

Important Client Code:

```
public class GameClient extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IGameClient {

    public GameClient(String name) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        this.name = name;
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        server = (IGameServer) registry.lookup("GameServer");
        server.login(this.name, this);
    }

    // some methods here    

}
```

The Important Ant Code:

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${export}/FlyHuntClient.jar">
        <fileset dir="${build}" />
        <fileset dir="." includes="res/**" />
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="client.GameClientLauncher" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="./" />
            <attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <jar destfile="${export}/FlyHuntServer.jar">
        <fileset dir="${build}" />
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="server.GameServer" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="./" />
            <attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <parallel>
        <java jar="${export}/FlyHuntServer.jar" fork="true" />
        <java jar="${export}/FlyHuntClient.jar" fork="true" />
    </parallel>
</target>
```

The Exception:

```
$ ant run
Buildfile: [trimmed...]/build.xml

run:
     [java] Nov 05, 2013 4:21:12 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
     [java] Feiner: RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: java.rmi.Remote lookup(java.lang.String)]
     [java] Nov 05, 2013 4:21:12 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
     [java] Feiner: RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: void rebind(java.lang.String, java.rmi.Remote)]
     [java] Nov 05, 2013 4:21:12 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCallException
     [java] Fein: RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1] exception: 
     [java] java.rmi.NotBoundException: GameServer
     [java]     at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:137)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
     [java] 
     [java] Nov 05, 2013 4:21:12 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
     [java] Feiner: RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl[0:0:0, 2]: java.rmi.dgc.Lease dirty(java.rmi.server.ObjID[], long, java.rmi.dgc.Lease)]
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.NotBoundException: GameServer
     [java]     at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:137)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:378)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at client.GameClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at client.GameClientLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: after developing the application further, the issue seems fixed now, but I have no idea what was wrong..

Comment: I suggest you forget about any problems you encounter running in the IDE or via ANT. They are of no practical interest or concern. The only thing that matters is the production deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are expecting all games terms to run on the same host as the server, you need to lookup the registry at the server, not at the client. Change the getRegistry() call to specify the server hostname.

Comment: but atm everything is started on the same host. the problem is that execution via ant fails, while it works fine if I start the two jars via command line.

Answer (score -1):

You are binding GameServer as a remote object in the stub and trying to get it as IgameServer. May be this could be the problem.

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099); 

Server server = new Server(); 

IGameServer iGameServer = (IGameServer) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0); 

// Bind the remote object's stub in the registry 

String bindingName = "Server"; 

registry.bind(bindingName, iGameServer); 

System.out.println("LOG DBG :[Server Ready Binding As " + bindingName +"]");
```

Try this. No need to implement UnicastRemoteObject here as the interface already implements it.

Comment: He is not doing anything 'in the stub'. He can't. The stub is generated, not coded by the OP. Interfaces cannot implement `UnicastRemoteObject`, or indeed anything else. Answer is basically nonsense.